# Service oriented and three-tier architecture together?

Tags: spring-mvc, soa, three-tier

Can I use SOA and three-tier in one application? Using SOAP to connect for external services, using MQ and Spring MVC. I have an application server and server for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that they are very different things.

There is a vast array of different SOA implementation styles, you can do it in so many ways. One is to have services talking to APIs over http where the APIs in question are written in a 3 tier style.

You can also have an event driven architecture where messages are passed on a message bus or a queue or some sort, the services reading and writing to those queues can be written in a three-tier style.

To sum up yes you can have SOA and three-tier in the same architectural solution, one does not exclude the other.

Does this help your decision on how to structure your service design and how to structure the wider solution architecture?